# Use the Refresh_Token to get another Access_Token every 1 hour in nodeJS express App

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, azure-ad-msal, passport-azure-ad

I have got an access_token and refresh_token using Passport.js (passport-azure-ad) OIDCStrategy in my NodeJS Express application. Now every 1 hour my access-token expires and access to the app gets revoked. How can I use the refresh token to get another access-token once the previous access token expires. I want to keep requesting this access-token every 1 hour using the refresh-token. Can someone help me with a snippet that I can use.

Comment: have you checked the examples in the doc? https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad
also, I will add a tag to make the question easier to find by its community

Comment: @germanio, Yes I have implemented the same OIDCStrategy and I get the ID_Token, Access_token and the Refresh_Token. But it looks like Passport-azure-ad is not using the refresh_token to get the next access_token once the access_token expires. Hence I wanted to check if there is a way to use the refresh token to get another access-token once it expires.

Comment: my understanding is very limited about this, but there should be a different endpoint to use the refresh_token and get what you want, sorry I can't help with this